# Mockito/GWT : mocked view's widgets are null

Tags: java, gwt, mockito, uibinder

I got a view (GWT MVP pattern) that contains a listbox.
I created a testcase using `@Mock MyView view`Then in one test I want to be able to have a hand on the list box object using :

```
ListBox listBox = GwtReflectionUtils.getPrivateFieldValue(view, "tableListBox");
```

This returns null.

I followed this tutorial : http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/wiki/SimpleUnitTest which using the same way.

The only difference I see is I'm using UIBinder, however it should be supported from what I've read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a mock, of course fields aren't set. When working with mocks you have to think about **interactions**, not state. (Actually this statement is true with generated mocks like those of mockito, powermock, easymock, etc.)

The wiki links examples don't use mocks, they show real objects!

I think you will be more interested by a **spy**. You can use @Spy.
In mockito 1.9.0 you can write :

```
@Spy MyView view = new MyView(paramA, paramB);
```

or if MyView has default constructor

```
@Spy MyView view = new MyView();
@Spy MyView view; // equivalent, mockito will call the default constructor
```

For more information take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was missing!